# Backslash Escape Sequence displaying both backslashes

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I currently have a string like this:

```
string login = "DOMAIN\" + userID
```

Obviously this does not work as I need the backslash escape sequence, right?

```
string login = "DOMAIN\\" + userID
```

This displays `DOMAIN\\jcwhisman` with 2 backslashes?

I have tried all of these in hopes that something will work. While these don't all display 3 slashes, none of them display what I need:

- `string login = @"DOMAIN\" + userID`
- `string login = @"DOMAIN\\" + userID`
- `string login = "DOMAIN\\" + userID`
- `string login = "DOMAIN\" + userID`

I know some of those don't seem logical, but I have just been trying everything I can.

I need it to display as `DOMAIN\jcwhisman`

Comment: there is no way to get `DOMAIN\\\jcwhisman` from this: `"DOMAIN\\" + userID`, unless your userId contains a backslash at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Your two ways are correct and should give you exactly what you want:

1. `string login = @"DOMAIN\" + userID`
2. `string login = "DOMAIN\\" + userID`

Just make sure that you don't have a *backslash* at the beginning of your `userID`.